# Observable controlled by variable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I try to get my HTTP-client-requests controlled by a variable.
But I am not sure how to set the filter.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
go : boolean = true;     // skip the request if false


ngOnInit ()
{
  interval (10000).pipe (
    startWith (0),
    mergeMap (obs => this.myservice.request ().pipe (catchError (error =>
    {
      console.log ("error: " + error);
      return empty ();
    })))).subscribe (resp =>
    {
      console.log ("response: " + resp);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `margeMap` could return different Observables based on the `go` variable:

```
mergeMap (obs => go ? this.myservice.request().pipe(...) : EMPTY)
```

where `EMPTY` can be imported from `'rxjs'` package.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use || operator

```
 mergeMap (obs => this.myservice.request().pipe(...) || null)
```